# Not sure how to structure code for a quiz program.

Tags: c

For the past 3 days I've written+deleted+written+deleted code for a homework assignment and I'm at wits end. This is the first time I've been stumped this semester, and I'm starting to go a little insane.

The basic idea:

Create a generic multiple choice quiz program

Questions will be stored in a text file in the structure as follows:

- The question
- The number of choices
- The choices themselves (each on a new line)
- The correct answer

Everything is fine and dandy however what is driving me crazy is the idea that the number of choices varies for each question, and that they're in the same file.

Could somebody please take a look at the code I've got so far and give me some direction.
This is homework, I don't want answers, just some help!

**Code**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
 
typedef struct _question {
char question[50];
int numChoices;
int numChoicesLine;
char choices[100][100];
char correctAns[50];
} Question;
 
 
void getQuestion (FILE file, int *firstLine) {
 
// init struct
Question q;
 
// array to store lines in the file
char lines[100][100];
 
int i = 0; // counter
 
// read all lines into lines array
while(fgets(lines[i], 100, &file))
{
// keep track of how many lines there are in the file
++i;
}
 
// i want j to reference the first line of each new question set
int j = *firstLine;
 
// get the question
strcpy(q.question, lines[j]);
printf("%s", q.question);
 
// get number of choices
for (int j = *firstLine; j < i; ++j)
{
// if the line is a number store that number into numChoices and which line of the file
// the number is found
 
if(atoi(lines[j]))
 
{
q.numChoices = atoi(lines[j]);
q.numChoicesLine = j;
break;
}
}
 
// store choices in array lines[k]
int k = 0;
for (k = q.numChoicesLine+1; k <= q.numChoices + 1; ++k)
{
// loop from the first choice to the last choice
 
fgets(lines[k], 100, &file);
strcpy(q.choices[k],lines[k]);
printf("-%s", q.choices[k]);
}
 
// store correct ans
// after the above loop, k refers to the line of the last choice in the quiz
strcpy(q.correctAns, lines[k]);
 
// set the firstLine to the line that stores the question for the next set
*firstLine = k + 1;
}
 
 
int main()
{
// open file
FILE *files;
files = fopen("tickle.txt", "r");
int firstLine = 0; // the first time it will be 0
getQuestion(*files, &firstLine);
return 0;
}
```

Example for the data file:

> Who is the President of the USA?
>
> 3
>
> George Bush
>
> Michael Jordan
>
> Barack Obama
>
> Barack Obama
>
> What country lies north of Mexico?
>
> 2
>
> USA
>
> Canada
>
> USA

Comment: Are you allowed to assume proper text-file format? That always makes things easier

Comment: Also, are you having any specific error messages, problems right now?  I know you say that the number of choices per question is driving you crazy, but are you having improper output, etc?

Comment: Think about other functions and classes that you could make that would help you organize things better.  For example, Is there a function you could write that would help you determine if an answer is a duplicate of one that was already read?

Comment: please post your code **here** don't post it into github 'cause if github disappears or the code is deleted from there, this question won't be usefull for anybody else :) thanks. As I already did, it's not necesary for this question ^^

Comment: @Frakcool There is no link on "here".

Comment: @LVBen by **here** I mean on his question (on Stack Overflow), no external links :)

Comment: Oh!!! OK!  Understood!

Comment: @duketon Are you suppose to present the questions as they appear in the file, or scramble the questions and present them in random order. If it's the former, you could make your life easier by reading one question at a time instead of trying to parse the whole file into memory.

Comment: @user3386109 It's the former, just one question at a time. I was actually thinking about this earlier. I might try this. I just need to get the procedure right, i.e -> Read question 1 -> Ask user the question -> Check validity, store score. Does that seem right?

Comment: @EyeOfTheHawks I am allowed to assume proper file format. I'm not getting any errors, just having trouble with the logic of the program. 

My main issue at the moment is storing each question into a struct. I might just try and start again, because what I have so far seems to be a mess!

Comment: @duketon Yes, that seems right.

Comment: @duketon not a bad idea to start over, just break down it into steps. First read the question, next is how many responses, after x responses is the answer, and repeat.  I recommend not reading in the full text file into a massive array, and filling up the structs as you go instead.

Comment: Since you're not having any particular problem with the code, and are mainly looking to improve/refactor/streamline it, this might be a good question for [codereview.se].  You'll get all the suggestions you could ever ask for, and then some.  :)

Comment: @cHao Thank you for that suggestion, I haven't come across that yet.


Just as a general note, I'm incredibly surprised as to how nice and helpful everyone has been in this thread. 

I'm pretty new to this community and this is a great intro :)

Comment: `void getQuestion (FILE file,` is incorrect. You should not pass a `FILE` by value. This code is not even required to compile; the definition of `FILE` could be invisible to your program.  Change to `FILE *file` - you should **always** refer to `FILE`s by a pointer.

Answer (score 2):

Here are a few helpful points:

Break up your getQuestion function into several smaller functions.  Try to name each of your functions in a way that accurately represents what the function does.

Think of *helper/utility* functions that you could write once and re-use.

Think about how to make your code cleaner, easier to read, understand, modify, and maintain.

Code that looks like this:

```
void GetQuestion ()
{
   DoStep1();
   DoStep2();
   DoStep3();
}

void DoStep1()
{
   DoStep1A();
   DoStep1B();
   DoStep1C();
}

void DoStep2()
{
   DoStep2A();
   DoStep2B();
   DoStep2C();
}

void DoStep3()
{
   DoStep3A();
   DoStep3B();
   DoStep3C();
}
```

is better organized than code like this:

```
void GetQuestion()
{ 
   ... // Step 1a
   ... // Step 1b
   ... // Step 1c
   ... // Step 2a
   ... // Step 2b
   ... // Step 2c
   ... // Step 3a
   ... // Step 3b
   ... // Step 3c
}
```

"DoStep" is likely not a good name for any of your functions.  I am using those names as a placeholder, so that you can figure out how to name your own functions.

Answer (score 1):

- use the `scanf` functions: they've been designed to deal with that kind of problem (line by line reading, simple patterns).
- translate the file record specs into `scanf` instructions, and don't forget to check the result of the call (check the [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html) of the function for further info).
- don't load all the file in one go into an array, it's much easier to process it directly line by line.
- for your `Question` data structure, you should know already how to manage memory dynamically using `malloc` (allocation) and `free` (disposal). Use that to match the number of answers (I suppose their maximum length is fixed at 100)
- as [LVBen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23793932/1769720) rightfully said, break down your code in meaningful units.

Comment: Thanks heaps for that, I'll get cracking in the morning with all these suggestions in mind. It's 1am and I'm dead tired! Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

One of biggest deals [that drive you insane] is :

```
for (k = q.numChoicesLine+1; k <= q.numChoices + 1; ++k)
```

actually you fetch your choices from `q.numChoicesLine+1` to `q.numChoicesLine+q.numChoices`
let's say you have 3 choices start from line 7, so you need to read lines 7, 8 , 9 using a for loop like :

`for(i=7; i< 7+3; i++)`

and not

`for(i=7; i<3; i++)`

My suggestion is to use the for loop like this:

`for (k = q.numChoicesLine+1; k <= q.numChoicesLine+q.numChoices; ++k)`

get it?